# CloudFormation fails with ec2:RequestSpotFleet IAM error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an AWS spot fleet through CloudFormation, but I'm getting this permission error. I'm creating this stack through a root account, so I don't see a possible reason for an IAM error via CloudFormation.

I'm creating this stack from the CLI with root account credentials.

Has anybody encountered this before?

[image: CloudFormation failure image]

Answer (score 0):

I would check the instructions for the [Amazon EC2 Spot Fleet Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/spot_fleet_IAM_role.html):

> If you create a managed compute environment that uses Amazon EC2 Spot
>   Fleet Instances, you must create a role that grants the Spot Fleet
>   permission to bid on, launch, tag, and terminate instances on your
>   behalf. Specify the role in your Spot Fleet request. You must also
>   have the AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot and AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet
>   service-linked roles for Amazon EC2 Spot and Spot Fleet.

Also, to quote the documentation on [Spot Fleet Pre-requisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#spot-fleet-prerequisites):

> If you use the Amazon EC2 console to create a Spot Fleet, it creates a
>   role named `aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role` that grants the Spot Fleet
>   permission to request, launch, terminate, and tag instances on your
>   behalf. This role is selected when you create your Spot Fleet request.
>
> If you use the AWS CLI or an API instead, you must ensure that this
>   role exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me! I'd seen that page before and I'm pretty sure that the correct role exists (https://imgur.com/d5jrIN8) Even so, I think that role is used by the Spot Fleet itself to manage itself, not by CloudFormation to create the new Spot Fleet.

Comment: It's possible that the CloudFormation launch tests that Spot Fleet can assume the named role and that it has the relevant permissions.

Comment: Hi, I've figured it out. Turns out my laptop's credential was a user with the AWS-managed PowerUserAccess policy (not the root user), and I'd forgot the distinction since they were basically the same. Creating the CF template on the AWS console (root user web access) worked. Sorry for the bother...

Comment: I fixed it by adding some additional IAM permissions (read, list, \*InstanceProfile\*) and crucially iam:PassRole (sigh) to the user.